# Patch routing error Rails 5 in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have no idea of the problem. Using gems devise and globalize.
I don't know if is the cause, but form_for generate wrong action in html, look:

form class="edit_status" id="edit_status_1" action="/1/statuses/update" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"

Id's placing before statuses. I don't know why.

**Form_for**

form_for(@status, url:statuses_update_path(@status), method: :post) do |f|

Setted method post because the controller was receiving *id = update* without it.

The problem detail below.

**Error**

```
No route matches {:action=>"/statuses/390022407", :controller=>"statuses", :status
=>{:content=>"Lorem ipsum"}}
```

**Routes.db**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|pl/ do
      post 'statuses/update'
      resources :statuses, only: [:update]
   end
end
```

**Rails routes**

[image: Routes]

**Controller**

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_locale

    def update
        #code...
    end

    private
        def status_params
            params.require(:status).permit(:content)
        end

        def set_locale
            I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
        end
end
```

**Test code**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StatusesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

    def setup
        @user = users(:brock)
        @status = statuses(:statusBrock)
        I18n.default_locale = :en
    end

    test "should not update when not logged in" do
        patch status_path(@status), params: { status: { content: "Lorem ipsum" } }
        assert_redirected_to new_user_session_path
    end

    test "should update when logged in user admin" do
        sign_in @user
        patch status_path(@status), params: { status: { content: "Lorem ipsum" } }
        assert_equal "Lorem ipsum", @status.content 
    end
end
```

Something's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not immediately clear to me what you're trying to do.

```
  post 'statuses/update'
  resources :statuses, only: [:update]
```

You have two routes defined here - one is a post to statuses/update which takes no additional arguments, and the second is /status/status_id.

You're then calling

```
statuses_update_path(@status)
```

And passing @status as an argument to the path, except that route doesn't accept an id param, it accepts a locale param.

Is there a reason you want the route to be statuses/update and not the more RESTful status/?.  I would remove the first route, and use the built in Rails naming conventions.

Edit:
Additionally, in your test code you're only testing the second route - it's not clear why you have these two different routes and you're switching between them.

Comment: I study most about RESTful and correct the code, removing the first route and using Rails naming conventions. I was using post ajax, so add wrong route, because not working ajax. But the problem was in the same ajax requisition. thanks for help.